How to kick some types out of a template parameter pack?
Given a class template Foo, one can use deduction guides to avoid specifying template arguments of Foo. For example:
template <typename... Types>
struct Foo
{
    template <typename... Ts>
    Foo(Ts&&...){}

    // hundreds of lines here ...
};

template <typename... Types>
Foo(Types...) -> Foo<Types...>;

int main() {
    Foo foo{42, 42L, 42.F};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(foo), Foo<int, long, float>>);

    return 0;
}

My question is, can some types from the template argument pack be ignored when deducing the type of Foo?
For example, is it possible to achieve this:
int main() {
    Foo foo{std::in_place_type<int>,   42,  
            std::in_place_type<long>,  42,
            std::in_place_type<float>, 42};
    
    // foo deduced to be of type Foo<int, long, float>
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(foo), Foo<int, long, float>>); // error

    return 0;
}

It is imaginable that this can be done using aforementioned deduction guides, but I am not able to get it right. My problem is in unpacking a tuple. This is the closest I get:
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <typename>
inline constexpr bool is_in_place_type_v = false;

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_in_place_type_v<std::in_place_type_t<T>> = true;

template <typename T>
using is_in_place_type = std::bool_constant<is_in_place_type_v<T>>;

template <typename Tuple, typename... Types>
struct tuple_extend;

template <typename... Types1, typename... Types2>
struct tuple_extend<std::tuple<Types1...>, Types2...>
{
    using type = std::tuple<Types1..., Types2...>;
};

template <typename Tuple, typename... Types>
using tuple_extend_t = typename tuple_extend<Tuple, Types...>::type;

template <typename...>
struct TrimImpl
{};

template <typename Result, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct TrimImpl<Result, T, Ts...>
{
    using result = TrimImpl<Result, Ts...>::result;
};

template <typename Result, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct TrimImpl<Result, std::in_place_type_t<T>, Ts...>
{
    using result = TrimImpl<tuple_extend_t<Result, T>, Ts...>::result;
};

template <typename Result, typename T>
struct TrimImpl<Result, T>
{
    using result = Result;
};

template <typename Result, typename T>
struct TrimImpl<Result, std::in_place_type_t<T>>
{
    using result = tuple_extend_t<Result, T>;
};

template <typename... Types>
struct Trim
{
    using impl = TrimImpl<std::tuple<>, Types...>;
    using result = impl::result;
};

template <typename... Types>
struct Foo
{
    template <typename... Ts>
    Foo(Ts&&...){}

    // hundreds of lines here ...
};

template <typename... Types>
requires (!(is_in_place_type_v<Types> || ...))
Foo(Types...) -> Foo<Types...>;

template <typename... Types>
requires (is_in_place_type_v<Types> || ...)
Foo(Types...) -> Foo<typename Trim<Types...>::result>;

int main() {
    Foo foo{std::in_place_type<int>,   42,  
            std::in_place_type<long>,  42,
            std::in_place_type<float>, 42};

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(foo), Foo<std::tuple<int, long, float>>>);
    // static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(foo), Foo<int, long, float>>); // error

    return 0;
}

Can this be made so that the second static_assert does not fire, while the first one does?

What's the point? Foo<int, long, float> foo(42, 42, 42) is much shorter and easier to write than Foo foo{std::in_place_type<int>, 42, std::in_place_type<long>,  42, std::in_place_type<float>, 42};

@IgorTandetnik If the types are not primitives, in this case, the benefit is in-place construction. But in general, I am curious if template parameter packs can be trimmed using deduction guides.

@lobelk, are you requiring that the class Foo and its ctor be not changed at all, wheras the deduction guide is the only thing we're allowed to change?

@Enlico Foo can be modified but it must not break where it is already used, assuming it was always used sensibly. So, adding new contructors, aliases etc. is fine, but renaming Foo into something else is, for example, not.

Grammar on CTAD only allow
template <..>
S(..) -> S<..>;

so
template <..>
S(..) -> typename SomeTrait<..>::type;

is wrong even when SomeTrait<..>::type is some S<..>.
So you cannot have what you want from template <typename... Types> struct Foo
but you can workaroud it with something like:
template <typename> struct FooImpl;

template <typename... Ts>
struct FooImpl<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
//...
};

then, you might have
template <typename... Types>
FooImpl(Types...) -> FooImpl<typename SomeTypeTraits<Types...>::type>;

// Convenient alias
template <typename... Types>
using Foo = FooImpl<std::tuple<Types...>;

Demo
With some issues when using CTAD from alias with clang.

And there is no way for a dependent token to be a pack, like SomeTrait<Foo...>::...types... (leading ... to introduce a pack, trailing ... to expand it)
